Customize Headless Identity verification SMS
We've configured Headless Identity, as specified in this guide: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/250/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/headless_identity_impl_guide.pdf
We have been trying out identify verification by SMS, but the SMS a new user receives upon registration looks like this:

Use XXXXXX to verify using Unknown on Unknown.

How can we modify the content of the SMS, most particularly the 'Unknown' parameters?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_custom_otp_beta.htm&release=250&type=5 (GA in Winter '25)

Thanks. I found that indeed and applied for the beta. But SF is also providing this standard solution, which I believe should be at least a bit configurable and not showing 'using Unknown on Unknown'.

Agreed on both counts. Create an idea on Idea Exchange, you'll have our vote.

So I received confirmation from SF that the SMS content is not editable in any way. Vote on this idea to change that: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000QeHHBUA3/make-the-headless-identity-verification-sms-customizable
